# Inverted filling of polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, rendering, fill

Is there a way to color on the outside of polygons like this?

I have tried to use the inverted polygon style in QGIS but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: What went wrong ? I think **inverted polygon** style is definitely the answer to your question ... as [Ed mentioned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255262/115) the **Mask plugin** is using this style to achieve masking (of selected objects) ...

Comment: Use the Geometry Checker plugin to check the validity of your polygon's geometry. If the geometry is invalid QGIS doesn't know where the outside of the polygon is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure what was going wrong with inverted polygon style, but here is a simple polygon to show you how to do it:

[image]

Go to Layer `Properties -> Style ->` Change `Single Symbol` to `Inverted polygons`

[image]

Notice I used the same color in your question because you want to color the outside polygon with this specific color.

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of another stylistic way to achieve that effect (if inverted pgons is not working), however, you could download the Mask plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mask/) which will automatically create an exterior mask around a selected polygon. It creates a new memory polygon layer that you can style however you want.

> This plugin allows user to quickly transform a polygon selection into
> a map masking layer or a region of interest, following symbology
> choice. The plugin allows also to spatially filter labeling of other
> layer, so that labels will only appear in the Region of Interest.

Comment: Make huge vector polygon over extend and clip two layer

Comment: That's what the mask plugin does.

Answer (score 3):

Despite a brilliant answer from @ahmadhanb, I would like to share an idea of how to invert a filling of polygon with *Geometry Generator*.

Let's assume that there is a polygon, shown on the Picture beyond.

[image: input]

Use the following setting for the Geometry generator

[image: input]

and get the result, see image below

[image: result]