# Cropping background map by shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, clip, basemap

I would like to crop OpenStreetMap by shapefile of the country in QGIS v3.12.1.

I knew some Plugin for that in the older version of QGIS however, it is not available anymore. So what are the options?

I am a user of Python GDAL and Rasterio so if there is some option, it would be also great.

Comment: I am a user of Python GDAL and Rasterio so if there is some option, it would be also great!

Comment: Just to be clear. Are you talking about OSM data for your country, clipping a rater or simply visualization of OSM basemap for a particular area? If OSM data then [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73238/loading-openstreetmap-data-in-qgis), for clipping a raster try [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/clipping-raster-with-vector-boundaries-using-qgis), if visualization then [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255259/inverted-filling-of-polygon). For cropping do you need a multi-scale map or just in a particular scale?

Comment: I am talking more about this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80488/how-to-clip-an-openlayers-osm-background-to-a-vector-boundary

Comment: Does that thread answer your question?

Comment: I am thinking about something more automatic/elegant way. However, if it is the only a solution or this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73048/how-do-i-clip-osm-basemap-with-a-polygon), it would be enough.