# How to create a boundary where the only things to be visualized from the main layer are inside that boundary

Tags: qgis, boundaries

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

I'm only interested in the things inside that polygon. How can I do that? I'm using QGIS 3.28.3 'Firenze'.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to create a box around visible items, or define a polygon and only show what is inside

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @Kasper i want to define a polygon and only show what is inside

Comment: You can set the symbology type of your boundary polygon to *Inverted Polygons*, then make the fill colour white (for example). See [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255259/inverted-filling-of-polygon-in-qgis).